# Grouping Technique SUM Database

Tags: oracle, sum, grouping

Good Morning, I am a junior database programmer.

I would like to the shortest way to write this code.

I would like to show afte I executed like this

```
fyear     money
<2012     4
2012      5
2013      5
2014      5
total     19
```

I have a code like this

```
SELECT fyear,SUM(money)
FROM (

          SELECT       CASE 
                         WHEN fyear < 2012 THEN ' <2012'
                         WHEN fyear = 2012 THEN   '2012'
                         WHEN fyear = 2013 THEN   '2013'
                         WHEN fyear = 2014 THEN   '2014'
                         END fyear, money

              FROM( 
                    SELECT fyear, money
                    FROM   table1
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT fyear, money
                    FROM   table2
                   )
 )GROUP BY fyear
```

This code above

```
fyear     money
<2012     4
2012      5
2013      5
2014      5
```

This is missing total. I am not sure that how I add "total", what is the best way to add "total" in the code?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need a [ROLLUP](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DWHSG/sql-aggregation-data-warehouses.htm#DWHSG8609):

```
select NVL(fyear, 'total') fyear, money 
from (
      SELECT fyear, SUM(money) money
      FROM (SELECT CASE
                      WHEN fyear < 2012 THEN '<2012'
                      WHEN fyear = 2012 THEN '2012'
                      WHEN fyear = 2013 THEN '2013'
                      WHEN fyear = 2014 THEN '2014' 
                   END fyear, money
              FROM (SELECT fyear, money FROM table1
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT fyear, money FROM table2
                   )
           )
      GROUP BY rollup(fyear)
     )
```

which gives:

```
FYEAR       MONEY
------ ----------
<2012           4
2012            5
2013            5
2014            5
total          19
```

As an aside, depending on your scenario, your `CASE` can probably be simplified:

```
CASE
   WHEN fyear < 2012 THEN '<2012'
   ELSE to_char(fyear)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union to add a total row as follows;

```
with line_tots AS
(SELECT fyear, SUM (curr_qty) as curr_qty
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN fyear < 2012 THEN ' <2012'
                  WHEN fyear = 2012 THEN '2012'
                  WHEN fyear = 2013 THEN '2013'
                  WHEN fyear = 2014 THEN '2014'
               END
                  fyear,
               curr_qty
        FROM  table_1)
GROUP BY fyear
ORDER BY fyear)
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT fyear, curr_qty
        FROM line_tots
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'total', SUM(curr_qty)
        FROM line_tots
        )
ORDER BY fyear
```

(I removed your sub query that selected from two tables as its unnecessary for the solution)

If you are using SQL*Plus then another way is to use a computed report column which requires no changes to your query.

```
SQL> compute sum label total of curr_qty on report
SQL> break on curr_qty on report
SQL> l
  1  SELECT fyear, SUM (curr_qty) as curr_qty
  2  FROM   (SELECT CASE
  3                    WHEN fyear < 2012 THEN ' <2012'
  4                    WHEN fyear = 2012 THEN '2012'
  5                    WHEN fyear = 2013 THEN '2013'
  6                    WHEN fyear = 2014 THEN '2014'
  7                 END
  8                    fyear,
  9                 curr_qty
 10          FROM  table_1)
 11  GROUP BY fyear
 12* ORDER BY fyear
SQL> /

FYEAR    CURR_QTY
------ ----------
 <2012         13
2012           10
2013           12
2014            9
       ----------
total          44
```